# Add new material to linked copy (without modifing the color of the original)

Tags: scripting

I am writing a method that make a linked copy of an object, move it, append to a collection and add a new material to it. The copy, move and append parts works, the material part not

```py
def object_duplicate_to_collection_and_move(obj, collection_name, random_loc):     
    # the new object is created with the old object's data, which makes it "linked"
    my_new_obj = bpy.data.objects.new("indiceDup", obj.data)
    # move to random location
    my_new_obj.location = random_loc
    # append to result collection
    dst_collection = bpy.data.collections.get(collection_name)
    dst_collection.objects.link(my_new_obj) 
    
    bpy.context.view_layer.objects.active = my_new_obj
    
    # the slot is correctly set to object
    bpy.context.object.material_slots[0].link = 'OBJECT'

    # from here on, nothing works. The material is not created, no error is returned
    bpy.context.object.active_material_index = 0
    bpy.ops.material.new()
    bpy.data.materials["Material.010"].node_tree.nodes["Principled BSDF"].inputs[0].default_value = (0.8, 0.0122428, 0, 1)
```

Comment: I don't think you can get away with setting the index to zero.  I believe you have to actually remove any materials from slots .  Also, is "Material.010" the material from the original object?  Changing it will change both.  You probably need to create a new material if you want the color to be different.

Comment: If I remove the materials from the slot, they disappear also from the original. What I actually want, is an original object containing 5 materials. Then I want to make x linked copies of that object, and for each copy assign a random material from the 5 original one.

Comment: Well, I solved the problem making the original material random, the color changes through "ObjectInfo" -> "Random" plugged into a color ramp. That is not the solution to my question, but at least to my problem,